# How to extract height of building and roof structure from nDSM data

Tags: qgis, workflow, building-heights, rooftop-building

I am working with QGIS; SAGA; OrfeoToolbox and I try to create LOD1 and LOD2 building models.

I need help to recreate LOD1 (or LOD2) building models from DSM / LIDAR data.
I have a footprints of buildings and both DTM, DSM and raw LIDAR Data.

**My LOD1 workflow and problems**

If building is homogenous then I know that I can use nDSM and ZonalStatistics with Max value to achieve LOD1. But what if in one building footprint there are many building parts with different heights? I attach SHP footprints and nDSM data for my buildings. You can see clear differences in building parts in both left and right building. I have to proceed 100 000 buildings that why I search for quite autonomous solution.
[image]

My Idea - Is there any way to create height break-lines in nDSM data - and then to run polygonize function and ZonalStatistics?
Any other suggestion?

**And now about LOD2**

I decided to create dense diamond fishnet, intersect with building footprints, and drape it on nDSM with 3D-multipolygon. But results don't look good enough. And I can't find way to simplify roof structures with similar angle. I wonder if there is any access to typ-of RANSAC generalisation function to simplify that areas?

What I have now:[image]

Any other suggestions and tips? how to achieve as accurate as possible LOD2 models inside QGIS?
Will be glad for any suggestions and tips.

Comment: I'd do it in two ways, the roofs with slopes and the flat one. For flat ones you could just use clusering to separate pixels in homogenous groups. For sloping areas you just take it as is. You can use a slope calculation, this way you'll be able to spot and handle hard breaks and gradual slopes. I hop this helps.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. 

I don't really understand. How do you cluster homogenous groups in raster file? There is option to reclassify, but it will lost a lot of details I guess and has to be done in manual way...
With or without slopes I can see hard breakes and gradual slopes, but I wonder if there is any way to extract these lines automaticaly, or it must be done manually. If you could please add some more details, or short gif, or images how you do it, I will be very glad.

Comment: You can use zonal stats to get some distribution stats such as the standard deviation, I forgot clustering was only for vector but grass has something. You could convert your pixels to feature and cluster, or use the grass tool or anything else. You could also extract the roofs only to reduce noise in the analysis. The saga plugin or some other plugin might have some other utilities, or create one if you can. If you absolutely want the line you could get the slope, extract high value pixels, polygonise, get centroids, convert to line and extend it to split the polygons.